# Catch and return error from Echo.join()

Tags: php, laravel, echo

I was working on a real time chat and faced a problem(my previous question) which i haven't found any solution to and i was wondering if i could actually catch an exception from Echo.join('my_channel').

My app.js code

```
window.Echo.join('chatit')
            .listen('MessagePosted', (e) => {
                 this.messages.push({
        console.log(e)
    });


    },
```

Comment: You'll have to show some of your code to get any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: I've added my code, but i really don't think it necessary. I just want to know if there's a way to catch echo errors.

Comment: I've added my code, but i really don't think it necessary. I just want to know if there's a way to catch echo errors. Besides I have already posted the full code in my previous question which i didn't get any response to @mypetlion